# How to give a simple repository-name to docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image

`docker image pull` requires exactly 1 argument `docker image pull [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG]`

When we download images from non standard repositories, a big REPOSITORY URL is prepended in `docker image ls` output.

**Action**
If I run following command

```
docker image pull artifactory-url/namespace/mydockerImage:123
```

**Current behavior**
The image listing will return

```
$ docker image ls  -a
REPOSITORY                                TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE    
artifactory-url/namespace/mydockerImage   123          acvsx1234     48 minutes ago    1.54GB
```

**Expected behavior**
Is there any option or other command I can use while pulling so I can have docker listing output  as following ?

```
$ docker image ls  -a
    REPOSITORY      TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE    
    mydockerImage   123          acvsx1234     48 minutes ago    1.54GB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retag the image and remove the old image.

e.g.

```bash
# Pull image
docker image pull artifactory-url/namespace/mydockerImage:123
# Retag image
docker tag artifactory-url/namespace/mydockerImage:123 myFunName:123
# Remove old tag (does not remove image as long as one tag points to it)
docker rmi artifactory-url/namespace/mydockerImage:123
```

Comment: Nick I want to preserve the old tag number, like 123 from original image. as mentioned in question. Is there a way to do it in one step ? Without actually looking at the version number and retyping it in new command.  I just meant to simplify  the repo name. my repo names are VERY long including namespaces

Comment: @ThrowableException Don't think there's a built in docker command to do that in one step. You could always write a bash function to do this and put it in your `.bashrc`.